# Homogeneous and nonhomogeneous matrices basics

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix where $m\lt n$

The nonhomogeneous system $Ax=o$ has at least one solution and the homogeneous system $Ax=0$ has a unique solution.

Are the above statements true or false ...please assist

Comment: Do you have two separate statements?

Comment: The first system looks pretty homogeneous.

Comment: @Dylan That may be a bad edit of mine. Reverting it...

Comment: You will have to take more care, Bulelwa, when you post questions here. Your first sentence ends in mid-air. Your non-homogeneous system isn't non-homogeneous. Your spelling leaves much to be desired. Voting to close.

Comment: @Gerry: The first question ended in "mid-air" because of the use of `<`; of course, the OP should look at how the question looks after posting. Th first system as `Ax=o`, as opposed to the second which is `Ax=0`; however, `o` is a rather poor choice for "something different from 0".

Comment: Bravo, Arturo, bravo! Unfortunately, the system forbids retracting my vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

If $m\lt n$ then the system has fewer equations ($m$) than unknowns ($n$) (variables) and it is not possible for the homogeneous system to have a unique solution.
The nonhomogeneous system may not have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

True, the matrix has more unknowns than rows than unknowns, so there must be free variables, which means that there must be several solutions for the non-homogeneous system, but only one for the homogeneous system.